# Calculated Fields and Outputting to Excel

Tags: calculated-column

So my issue is with SharePoint 2007 and what is happening is that when I output to a excel spread sheet a custom view, If I export some calculated columns it also brings in the columns that were used to calculated that column, even if those columns are not in the current view.

So I tested this like so. I made a view with just 1 column Annualized Savings which is a calculated field `=(savings 2012 + savings 2013)`. Then I simply hit export to spreadsheet, and I get two extra columns Savings 2012 and savings 2013 even though I only had the annualized savings in my view.

I personally have a feeling its because I used a custom Form, but I want to use my custom layout I made in the **NewForm**, and **EditForm**.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do this is a Sharepoint Designer Workflow.

But first set up your field.  Delete the calculated field and create a number field. [Annualised Savings]

Set the WorkFlow to start Automatically...
in your first Workflow Step

Set your condition Compare  list field
          Say if [Annualised Savings] is Empty.

Then add as your action 
          Do Calculation to Calculate Savings 2012 plus Savings 2013
          Save this to a variable Named AnnualisedSavings
Add another action
          Set Field in current item.. 
          Set your Annualised Savigs Field from your "Workflow Data" Field AnnualisedSavings

Then Display your new [Annualised Savings] field in your view and export this.

Note same can be done for concatenating fields together, using the dynamic string builder action, same method as above.